# Cannot delete s3 object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, amazon-iam

I create an IAM user and attach AWS default `AmazonS3FullAccess` policy to this user.

[image]

For the S3 part, I grant the upload/delete permission as well.
[image]

I can upload file to my S3 bucket using the user's access key and secret key by python `boto`. However, I cannot delete the object I just uploaded. The response is always `Access Denied`.

Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: If there is any matching policy statement, anywhere, that would deny a specific action, the action will be denied, even if other statements allow it.  Does the bucket have a bucket policy?  If so, that is the first place to look.

Comment: I find out there is a rule that deny any delete action in `AmazonElasticTranscoderRole` policy. That's why I can upload object but cannot delete it.

Comment: @YuLiang I'm also facing the same issue. How did you solve your problem?

Comment: I gave up `AmazonElasticTranscoderRole`, and made my own custom policy to fit my need.